# Wordpress after migration doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, http-status-code-404

I had problems with WordPress migration from one server to another, and generally now it works but I have many smaller problems..

Before I use domain oldexample.com and now i use domain newexample.com/something . Generally everything on the page works but changing language isn't work (qTranslate plugin).

I think that I found the reason of this - in admin menu I found in some places situation that href links start from "/" for example: "/wp-admin/..." and in result it change the URL from newexample.com/something/wp-admin to newexample.com/wp-admin. I see this problem in qTranslate settings links and when I want delete some plugins.  I get the error message "404 Not Found - nginx/1.4.5" in results...

Did you see this problem before? Maybe I should change something in WordPress core files? .htaccess? Now it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?newexample\.com\/something$ [NC]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Maybe you have to check your vhost.conf ? And redefine document root ?

Comment: But this blog use hosting company and I don't have access to  vhost.conf...

Comment: Do a [serialized search/replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) for URLs and server paths.

Comment: I change all database of course before, and I change all "http://oldexample.com" to "http://newexample.com/something". And after this operation I still have this problem...

Comment: After long time I find the solution! All "href" are generated by using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and this variable show only the rest part of the path (without /something/.

I add to wp-settings.php this part of code:
 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/something'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; (on the very beggining) all forms generate good path .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time I find the solution! All "href" are generated by using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and this variable show only the rest part of the path (without /something/. I add to wp-settings.php this part of code: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/something'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; (on the very beggining) all forms generate good path.